# XSLT How to use substring-after and concate multiple times for one string

Tags: xslt, concatenation, rtf

I have a little problem and I just can't seem to figure it out. I have a RTF string in an XML and want to cut out images there. That works so far. But now I have the problem that the string is only checked and shortened once. But there can be between 0 and infinite images attached. I do not understand how I can replace all of them, i.e. execute concat several times.

Thanks so much for your help

XML File:
`https://pastebin.com/6iVuFasn`

My XSL Code:

```
<xsl:variable name="storyFormattedText" select="//STORY_TEXT_RTF"/>
<xsl:variable name="textWithoutImages">
        <xsl:value-of select="$storyFormattedText"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($storyFormattedText,'{\result{\pict{\*\picprop}')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($storyFormattedText,'{\result{\pict{\*\picprop}'),substring-after($storyFormattedText,'}}}'))"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:call-template name="create_field">
                        <xsl:with-param name="field_id">15</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="field_type">1</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="field_name">Formatted Text ohne Bilder</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="is_empty">no</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($storyFormattedText,'{\result{\pict{\*\picprop}'),substring-after($storyFormattedText,'}}}'))"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, you can use the `replace()` function with regex to remove all occurrences of a substring with known prefix and suffix. In XSLT 1.0, you need to use a recursive named template - see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202265/3016153.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint and your help :) . It works.